# Can I change the styling of the code box in a markdown file with scss?

Tags: sass, markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I am trying to find out if I can effect the code box inside of a mark down document with scss?

I am working on a jekyll project and I am using markdown for my posts. Id like to edit the styling of the code box inside of the .md but cant seem to figure it out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262698/inline-html-is-escaped-by-jekyll)

> Kramdown treats each new line as a row and doesn't render Markdown bullet lists inside table cells, and instead of rendering HTML, it is escaped and outputted as a single line of text.
>
> You can tell Kramdown to leave the HTML alone and output as is, with the nomarkdown extension. Just wrap the HTML code with {::nomarkdown} ... {:/}

```
| Name | Value                                   |
|------|-----------------------------------------|
| one  | {::nomarkdown}<i>foo</i>{:/}            |
| two  | {::nomarkdown}<ul><li>bar</li></ul>{:/} |
```